# tools to get a list of all the subroutines(methods, functions)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know of any tools to get a list of all the subroutines(methods, functions) in my projects.
I have 6projs in one solution and need a basic tabular list with method name, called by(if possible), any other project details(would be helpful)
I am using Microsoft visual studio 2010, C#

Thanks
Sun.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would probably be [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/), as it can traverse your call hierarchy and generate graphs, tables, etc. but it's somewhat pricey.
Or, for free, you write a script that can use the [generated documentation files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4sa0ak0.aspx) to list the methods/classes, but the hierarchy will be difficult.  Or you could use a script to iterate through the C# files, though that's probably much more error prone.

Comment: I need it put in a word document just to meet the documentation req. Get all the names of methods, called by methods in a table

Comment: I found a script on one of the questions in stackoverflow. Type myType = typeof(myclassname);
MethodInfo[] myArrayMethodInfo = myType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
for (int i = 0; i <= myArrayMethodInfo.Length - 1; i++) {
 MethodInfo mi = (MethodInfo)myArrayMethodInfo(i);
 Debug.Print(mi.Name);
} But not sure where to add this script and what is myclassname

Comment: That'll list the methods at runtime.  You probably want to generate this list offline.  Also, getting a call heirarchy from that will be near impossible unless you want to work through the IL.  Which is where NDepend shines.